# Subclassing notepad’s Edit class (WINAPI)

Tags: winapi, callback, subclass, setwindowshookex

I have set a SetWindowsHookEx on the Edit class of notepad, but I am not sure how to continue from here.

I wish to subclass the Edit class to my own procedure, then manipulate the text or just save it to a file, then it must be send back the notepad control/class.

There are easier ways to get the text from notepad, but I am trying to learn WINAPI and Subclassing so this is a good way for me to learn it.

My SetWindowsHookEx looks like this:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, g_hInstDll, npThreadId);
```

How do I use the hook type : **WH_GETMESSAGE** to get the text from the Edit class in notepad and transfer it to my GetMsgProc(I think) function?

Is it the right hook type at all?

Do I send it a message? If yes, how do I do that?

My code look like this:

**dllHeader.h:**

```
#ifdef DLLAPI
#else
#define DLLAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
DLLAPI bool hookNotepad();
```

**dll.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define DLLAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#include "dllHeader.h"

// Forward references
LRESULT WINAPI GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// Global variables
HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;        // Hook for Notepad 'EDIT' class
HINSTANCE g_hInstDll = NULL; // DllMain entry (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
HWND npHWND = NULL;          // Notepad handle
DWORD npThreadId = NULL;     // Notepad thread ID
HWND npeHWND = NULL;         // Notepad 'EDIT' class handle


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,  DWORD ul_reason_for_call,  LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInstDll = hModule;
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

bool hookNotepad ()
{
    npHWND = FindWindow(TEXT("Notepad"), NULL); // Finds Notepad

    if (npHWND) //Notepad found
    {
        npeHWND = FindWindowEx(npHWND, NULL, L"Edit", NULL); // Finds the 'EDIT' class in notepad
        npThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(npeHWND, NULL); //Find ThreadID for Notepad 'EDIT' class
        g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, g_hInstDll, npThreadId); //Set hook in Notepad 'EDIT' class

        if (g_hHook) //if the hook is a succes then...
        { 
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Hook set in Notepad EDIT class!"), NULL, MB_OK); 
            // Now what? How to subclass the npeHWND (The 'EDIT' class of Notepad) to my own procedure? 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("SetWindowsHookEx error!"), NULL, MB_OK); //If the hook fails.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("This never get called. Why?"), NULL, MB_OK);
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

**exe.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <strsafe.h>

#include "C:\Users\Kristensen\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\dll\dll\dllHeader.h"

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int) 
{

    hookNotepad();
    return 0;
}
```

I am a bit a lost on how to proceed from here…  Any hints? Links? Tips?

I have read the documentation on MSDN regarding the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function – but I did not find a clear answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WH_GETMESSAGE` is called when the hooked thread calls `GetMessage()` or `PeekMessage()` to retrieve a message from its message queue, but not all messages go through the message queue, so you may have to use the `WH_CALLWNDPROC/RET` hooks as well, depending on what kind of messages you are trying to intercept.

Your global variables need to be stored in a block of shared memory or else they will only be accessible to the process that installs the hook, since a new copy of the DLL gets loaded when hooking other processes.

You cannot subclass an `HWND` that is owned by another process.  You would have to inject code into that process and then that code can subclass locally as needed.  `SetWindowsHookEx()` can be used to inject code into other processes, but `CreateRemoteThread()` may be better to use for that, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. WH_GETMESSAGE is more clear now. Good point with the global variables. Thanks again.